# Right vs Left Derivatives

Tags: differentiation, fermions, calculus, grassmann-numbers, superalgebra

Let $\theta$ be a fermionic quantity and $f(\theta)=f(0)+\theta\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}=f(0)+\frac{\partial_r f}{\partial\theta}\theta$. Under a variation $\theta\mapsto\theta+\delta\theta$ we have
$$f(\theta)\mapsto f(\theta)+\delta\theta\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta},$$
using the first formula, or
$$f(\theta)\mapsto f(\theta)+\frac{\partial_r f}{\partial\theta}\delta\theta,$$
using the second one. However,
$$\delta\theta\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}=(-1)^{|\delta\theta|(|f|+|\theta|)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}\delta\theta=(-1)^{|\delta\theta|(|f|+|\theta|)+|\theta|(|f|+1)}\frac{\partial_rf}{\partial\theta}\delta\theta$$
which is different from $\frac{\partial_rf}{\partial\theta}\delta\theta$ in general. This yields a contradiction between both variations. Of course problems are avoided if $|\delta\theta|=|\theta|$ but I don't see how this affect the first two equations. I am very confused by this!

Comment: The problem also doesn't appear if $|f|=|\theta|$. Thus, there is a sign difference if and only if $|f|=|\delta\theta|=|\theta|+1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, by definition the Grassmann parity $|\delta z|$ of a variation $\delta z$ of a [supernumber](https://planetmath.org/Supernumber) $z$ (of definite Grassmann parity) is the same as the Grassmann parity $|z|$ of the supernumber $z$ itself:
   $$|\delta|~=~0.\tag{1}$$
2. Perhaps OP is wondering about the following question.

   *Question:* How does an infinitesimal variation $\delta$ relate to a left [vector-field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field)/[linear derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(differential_algebra)) $X$ of Grassmann-parity $|X|$?

   *Answer:* In order to relate $X$ to an infinitesimal variation$^1$ $$\delta~=~\epsilon X,\tag{2L}$$
   one needs to introduce an infinitesimal parameter $\epsilon$ of the same Grassmann-parity $|\epsilon|=|X|$.

--

$^1$ For a right vector-field/linear derivation $X_R$, we instead have
$$\delta~=~X_R \epsilon ,\tag{2R}$$
with $|\epsilon|=|X_R|$.